# How to refresh only the textarea part without refreshing the whole page

Tags: php

I have a script:

```
<?php
header("refresh: 7;");
include 'theme.php';
ceklogin();
css();
exec('/www/openvpn_wget_status.sh');
echo '<br>';
echo file_get_contents( "/www/openvpn_status.txt" );
echo '<textarea readonly> Content Here </textarea></div></body></html>';
>?
```

It refreshes the whole page every 7 seconds, is there a way to refresh only the textarea instead of the whole page? I'm a copy and paste kind of guy so please explain in detail if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Short answer: use Javascript and AJAX.

Comment: That's not helping at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript and get the contents of the text file, if it's publicly accessible (and assuming `/www` is your webroot):

```
<script>
    function getFileContents() {
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open('GET', '/openvpn_status.txt');
        client.onreadystatechange = function() {
            document.querySelector("textarea").value = client.responseText;
        }
        client.send();
    }
    setInterval(getFileContents, 7000);
</script>
```

This code first creates a function called `getFileContents()` which literally goes out to a file named `openvpn_status.txt` in your web root directory and loads the contents into the first element matching the `textarea` node type.

It then sets the interval that this function is called to 7000 ms, or 7 seconds.